# How to extend the functionality of Open and Save dialogs of OS X applications?

Tags: software-recommendation, dialog

On Windows there are several third-party applications that can be used to improve the standard Open and Save dialogs.

I am looking for features like:

- Being able to delete files from the these dialogs.
- Being able to move files.
- Remember dialog size or common directories per application (not all apps are able to do things like this).

If the solutions are commercial, please mention the price.

Comment: I understand the desire to know prices, but they change so why not just link to the software.

Comment: @bmike product feautures can also change (even more often than price) - the whole point is to give good answers, clicking links and trying each product is a time wasting. Thats's the beauti of a wiki, if it get's outdated, someone will update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step one - try the free trial of [DefaultFolderX](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) (30$).

Step two - buy it.

These is no step three. It's that good.

Comment: I was just going to post the same. It's been around for many years and never caused grief. Great piece of UI extension.

Comment: @bmike, does DefaultFolderX suffice all features required?

Comment: It suffices for the three functions mentioned, but does much more than the OP has asked.